# Update all foreign key relationships of a record to point at another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two entries in a usertable:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| User_1 | Bob |
| User_2 | Jane |

There are various foreign key relations against the ID column.

Is there a simple way to merge User_2 into User_1 and update all foreign key relationships pointing at User_2 to now be pointing at 1? I don't need to keep the name or anything else, just that everything pointing at User_2 should point at User_1 instead.

The table is set up with cascading foreign keys so if I were to update User_1 to User_Abc all foreign key relationships will update to point at User_Abc. Ideally I'd like to just do it in the one place and avoid having to update a massive query that manually updates all foreign key relationships.

However I'm contrained by the fact I can't change the ID of User_1.

Comment: is the good old sql `update` keyword not fit the bill?

Comment: Update will cause a PK conflict because User_1 already exists.

Comment: If you don’t want to write a number of UPDATE statements then you’d have to query the information schema for the foreign keys and dynamically build and execute the update statements. Whether that is quicker than writing the individual update statements depends on the number of keys and your skill at writing the necessary code

Comment: @NickW I see, and there's definitely no way to do it with some sort of merge magic? I can  definitely do it manually wa sjust hoping it wouldn't come to that haha.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data in the related table and how it should look after the merge.